# Real-time desktop notifications for Stack Exchange inbox ( Chrome / Firefox )

Tags: app, chrome-extensions, notifier, inbox, firefox

### Screenshot

[image: unread messages in your inbox]

More screenshots: https://github.com/Rob--W/stackexchange-notifications/tree/master/screenshots

### About

Get real-time desktop notifications for your inbox at the Stack Exchange.

After installing and setting your Stack Exchange account ID, you will get desktop notifications whenever the inbox notification count changes. Click on the notification to visit your inbox.

**NEW in 2.2**: The unread message count is also displayed on the extension button, and
clicking on the extension button will directly show the contents of your inbox
in a panel. There is a "mark as read" button to mark all messages as read.

Don't want to receive notifications any more? Visit options and click on Stop.

#### Download

- Chrome Web Store: [Desktop Notifications for Stack Exchange](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/desktop-notifications-for/ijglncoabcgieiokjmgdogpefdblmnle)
- Firefox Add-on: [Desktop notifications for Stack Exchange's inbox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/real-time-desktop-notificat)
- Github: [Rob--W/stackexchange-notifications](https://github.com/Rob--W/stackexchange-notifications)

#### Platforms

It is supported by Chrome and Firefox, because they are the only browsers that support Desktop notifications out-of-the-box.

### Contact

Drop an issue at [Github](https://github.com/Rob--W/stackexchange-notifications/issues), or post an answer/comment here.

### Code

Used technologies: JavaScript, Chrome Extension API, WebExtensions API, Web Sockets, Stack Exchange API.

Comment: Can this extension notify me about new questions with a given tag?

Comment: @reprogrammer Technically, yes. Can you post a feature request with desired details as an answer, or [create an issue on Github](https://github.com/Rob--W/stackexchange-notifications/issues/new)? In particular, how do you imagine this feature, what determines whether a post is "new" or "read"?

Comment: Hi Rob, this can be done in Firefox too. The [HTML5 Notifications for Firefox](https://code.google.com/p/ff-html5notifications/) extension let's Firefox use window.webkitNotifications in the same way as you consume the API in Chrome. Your extension would of course depend on another Firefox extension, but you'd have at least [one avid user](http://stackapps.com/a/3808/4812). See [this meta post for more details](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/157534/155826). Hope this helps!

Comment: wud be cool for it to use more native notifications on OSX. 
I.e, currently the app pops up with it's own notification system instead of using Chrome's native notifications. But great otherwise.

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev The Chrome extension is using Chrome's native [notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications).

Comment: @RobW Thank you for quick response.  Hmm, I'm using Chrome Canary with experimental OS X notification feature: "chrome://flags/#enable-native-notifications". All notifications (Facebook/Google calendar etc..) looks like so: http://i.imgur.com/btW1yxf.png
    But Stackoverflow notifications look different, they have a square something like: http://i.imgur.com/uytXp.png     I kinda wonder why.. The reason I care is native notifcations stick around for later review in OSX's notification bar along with all other notifications. Any ideas? I wouldn't mind trying to fix it if given tips/advice?

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev Ah, native in that sense. I don't have a mac, but can you try out the following: 1. Open chrome://extensions, enable developer mode. Click on Inspect background page at my extension. Click on the sources tab, select "using-websocket.js" and set a breakpoint at the first line. Then run `delete chrome.notifications;` in the console. Then copy-paste https://gist.github.com/Rob--W/5926727 in the console and run it. Then continue the breakpoint, and generate a notification (e.g. by calling `setUnreadCount(1);` ). Does that give the desired result?

Comment: @RobW  Cool. This works :-D!. Before/After pictures: http://imgur.com/a/bW5eQ   Now notifications do look native to OS X. Pretty :-3.   They also stick around in notification bar.
Is there a way to enable it permanently? Is this in the latest source?
(Mind you, OS X notifications are only half-backed at present, in current stable chrome they're pretty meh. But on Canary they're pretty decent).

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev Cool. I've opened a new to-do (https://github.com/Rob--W/stackexchange-notifications/issues/21). I put the steps for the implementation, if you want to you can create a pull request.

Comment: @RobW kewl. I posted in the request.

Comment: Desktop notification not working ?

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Can somebody please port this to Firefox? I would definitely appreciate it.

FF Desktop Notification support: https://code.google.com/p/ff-html5notifications/

Comment: It took some efforts, but I've managed to port the extension to a Firefox add-on. I'll update the first post once it has passed review at AMO. Till then, you can get it from the Github repository at https://github.com/Rob--W/stackexchange-notifications/tree/master/Firefox.

Comment: @RobW Awesome! I'll be a beta tester and help you out with bugs! Thank you so much! I will tell you if I ever manage to get it built... (I _hate_ building code from source. It's hard, buggy, and almost never succeeds.) I will give it a shot, though.

Comment: @RobW Ummmmm.... what file am I supposed to download? I have never done this before, and there are no good instructions anywhere. Am I supposed to download all the files to the same folder, then change to that folder, and run the command? Am I supposed to find a "Download as .zip" link, and then run the command on that? What do I do?

Comment: @RobW Oh, wait. I poked around for a bit, then managed to find an XPI file. (_THAT_, I knew what to do with.) The configuration windows appeared for a minute, but I can't seem to make it come back.

Comment: Hey, I don't know whether it's turned on or not. Can somebody reply to this comment, so I can see if it's working?

Comment: You can install the extension with a few clicks at the Add-on gallery: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/real-time-desktop-notificat/. I have added [usage notes to Github](https://github.com/Rob--W/stackexchange-notifications#firefox-add-on) (and this question's first post), I hope that it's more clear how to use it.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude - In your SO profile, click "network user", then grab the uid out of the url. Then in Firefox, just disable and re-enable the extension and the configuration window will pop up and you can paste in your accountId (or "uid" as Rob W calls it)

Comment: @jmort253 Okay, so in the first box, I need to put `9121977`, and the second one needs to have `https://stackexchange.com/users/1921977/jamestheawesomedude?tab=inbox`, right? Or do I need to put `http://stackexchange.com/users/1921977/?tab=inbox`?

Comment: I faced the following issues: 1) every time I start FF I see add-on config screen. That's a bit annoying( 2) It would be nice to have option to show notification only once for new message(s) - currently it still shows notes once every few minutes until they're still in "Unread" state.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude I was redirected from this META thread: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/165086/208917 QA at your service, good luck with fixes)

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude Unfortunately FF plugin does not work anymore: perhaps SE changed something, but Socket can't start listening... Could you fix please?

Comment: @PeterL. Are you still experiencing problems? I'm using the add-on myself, and get notifications as expected. The notifications are triggered whenever a new message is emitted on the Web socket, or when a new message is found after restoring the network connection. If you're seeing multiple notifications, then either the socket connection keeps dropping, or someone has deleted a message, then posted a new one. (PS. I'm the OP, the author of this add-on)

Comment: @RobW now it's working fine - about a month ago it was updated automatically (at least it appears so)

Comment: @RobW I am running FF 16.0.1, and the Socket Status flickers between "listening" and "stopped" about once every half-second.  Is this to be expected, or no?

Comment: @anorton That's not the expected behaviour (and does not happen here, FF 22). Consider upgrading your browser, see also [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/135062/firefox-cant-establish-a-connection-to-the-server-at-ws-sockets-ny-stackexcha "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/").

Comment: @RobW I use chrome (latest version 30) and the extension is running but i dont get notifications.... any reason ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Oops, it was caused by a typo. I've [resolved](https://github.com/Rob--W/stackexchange-notifications/commit/9921c60b#diff-2) the error and published the new version. You will get the new version within an hour.

Comment: @RobW Glad I could help :-) p.s. do you have a link for a good tutorial for writing extensions for chrome ? ( for beginners) ?

Comment: @RobW  Where is the API for getting notification from stack exchange ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir My extension uses Web sockets to get real-time notifications. This is also used (internally) by Stack Overflow/Exchange. In addition, the official Stack Exchange API is used to get the latest notification count after regaining internet connection (or starting your browser). See https://api.stackexchange.com/ for this one.

Comment: Hmm, no activity here for an awfully long time; is it safe to assume that the extension is no longer supported, or maybe I'm in the wrong place?  I signed in with a token, successfully received one inbox notification from the extension, and they haven't shown up since.

Comment: @asheedawg Yeah, apparently I'm talking to myself since I'm the only activity on the post for 2+ years, but thought I'd pass along that, regardless of my previous comment, this add-in works fine...  maybe if I post it as an answer someone would notice ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably talking to myself here since it appears nobody except me has been on this page in *years*, but I figured I should mention that (contrary to my previous comment) **the add-in still works just fine**, and I've been using the Firefox version daily *(minutely?!)* for months without issue.

If the developer(s) *were* around, I'd have a couple minor feature requests, but in the meantime, the add-in does *exactly* what it says, and is actually more attractive than the original [post](https://stackapps.com/q/3780/50270) might lead you to believe...

[image: img: notification]
                                [image: arrow]

[image: image: S.E. Inbox]
              <sup><sup>(As rendered with Firefox 56/Windows 7)</sup></sup>

Comment: I'm still around. The exact appearance of the desktop notification depends on the browser and operating system. I saw your Github issue and will get back to that later.

Comment: The GitHub issue wasn't a big deal - great that's you're still around.  Does the app have many active users?

Comment: I don't know, I don't keep track. You could take a look at the extension galleries and sum the shown number of active users to get an estimate.

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network). This allows users to get notifications about any activity on a question when they follow it.

> [image: follow question popup]

However, this extension does not work properly with the new feature. The extension successfully notifies the user when they have a notification from a followed question, but fails to actually display the notification. As a result, the user has to navigate to the actual Stack Exchange site in order to view the notification.

Comment: I don't know whether this information is available in the API. I've asked whether this information can be access through the API at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network#comment1159131_345661

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have a stuck "1" notification, even though I've read everything in my inbox.  Didn't this used to have a "mark as read" button or am I crazy?  Either way, how do I make this 1 go away?

[image]

Comment: Clicking on the "Mark as read" button should work, provided that you're logged in. Do you see a "1" on your inbox when you visit a StackExchange website? Do you see any unread notifications on the website?

Comment: When I posted this I *did not have* a "mark as read" button (as mentioned in the post).  But it is there now and it did work as expected.  Very strange.