# Stack Exchange Notifications: inbox, achievements, score, improve text editor and lightbox

Tags: app, comments, notifier, inbox

### Install

- [**Chrome**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackexchangenotification/jcjhifljlkmoodmebfiimpoofdehnhia)
- [**Firefox**](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/stackexchangenotifications/)
- [**Edge**](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/lghbdnpkdcibhhdmfdbnekaffdliiadb)
- [**Opera**](https://addons.opera.com/extensions/details/stackexchange-notifications/)

> **Note:** you can install developer edtion (inclusive in google chrome) if download from https://github.com/brcontainer/stack-exchange-notifications/releases and follow steps in [**Debugging in Opera or Chrome**](https://github.com/brcontainer/stack-exchange-notifications#debugging-in-opera-or-chrome)

---

### Features

- Notifies about new messages in inbox (custom)
- Notifies about new achievements, like upvotes, downvotes, badges, privileges (custom)
- Fullscreen post-editor (full-view-port)
- Lightbox for images in posts and chat
- Save shortcut to chat rooms
- Markdown shortcut for **comment fields**

  1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for code
  2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for link
  3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for bold
  4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for italic

---

### License

[MIT](https://github.com/brcontainer/stack-exchange-notifications/blob/master/LICENSE)

### Issues

Send issues to https://github.com/brcontainer/stack-exchange-notifications/issues

### Open-source

The extension is written in HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

You can get the code here: https://github.com/brcontainer/stack-exchange-notifications (or vir `GIT`)
*(look in the `chrome/` folder for the Opera or Chrome code)*.

More details in: https://github.com/brcontainer/stack-exchange-notifications#for-developers

### Screenshots

- [Inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FS0H.png)
- [Achivements and score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LqNo.png)

### Inbox and achivements push notifications

> [image: inbox and achivements push notifications]

### Post editor in fullsize

> [image: improved editor]

### See linked post images in lightbox:

> [image: lightbox]

### Shortcut button for copy codes:

> [image: copy codes]

### Shortcut for saved chat rooms:

> [image: save room]
>
> Saved shortcut rooms in popup (before and after):
>
> [image: shortcut rooms]

Comment: [Related](https://stackapps.com/questions/3780/real-time-desktop-notifications-for-stack-exchange-inbox-chrome-firefox)